# Ionic 2 map marker not displaying

Tags: google-maps, ionic2

I am using Ionic 2.
It shows maps but zoom and marker does not show on map.
The code I use is given below.
No error, still not working.

```
let element: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('map');

let map: GoogleMap = this.googleMaps.create(element);

let latlang=new LatLng(43.0741904,-89.3809802);

map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY)
.then(() => {
    let position: CameraPosition = {
        target: {
            lat: 43.0741904,
            lng: -89.3809802
        },
        zoom: 10,
        tilt: 30
    };
    map.moveCamera(position);

    let markerOptions: MarkerOptions = {
        position: latlang,
        title: 'Ionic'
    };

    let marker=map.addMarker(markerOptions)
    .then((marker:Marker)=>{
        marker.showInfoWindow();
    });

    console.log('Map is ready!');
    // Now you can add elements to the map like the marker
});
```